# HTML form with post not calling PHP script in action

Tags: php, forms, http-post

I have a form in a HTML file that will post values from the form into a database, via a PHP script.

Unfortunately, when I click the submit button, my form will not call the PHP script. However, if I type in the URL of the PHP file, the PHP file will run and insert a blank row in the database. Therefore, my guess is that my HTML file never calls the PHP script.

Since I am new to PHP and HTML forms, is there any improvements or mistakes I can correct in my code?

Here is my HTML form:

```
<form id="frmRegister" action="dbase/insert.php" method="post" >
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><br /></th>
        <td><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">First Name:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="FirstName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Last Name:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="LastName" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Email Address:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Email" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Phone Number:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Phone" maxlength="10"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Username:</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="Username" maxlength="10"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Password:</th>
        <td><input type="password" name="Password" maxlength="10"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th align="left">Re-Enter Password:</th>
        <td><input type="password" name="Password2" maxlength="10" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><br /></th>
        <td><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><input type="button" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="Validate();"/></td>
        <td align="center"><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
// Connect to MySQL
$db = mysql_connect("", "nemo008", "CimesFungo");

if (!$db)
{
    exit("Error - Could not connect to MySQL");
}

$er = mysql_select_db("cs329e_fall11_nemo008", $db);

if (!er)
{
    exit("Error - Could not select the database");
}

$query = "INSERT INTO tblMembers (Username, Password, FirstName, LastName, Email, Phone, Year, Major)
VALUES ('$_POST[Username]', '$_POST[Password]', '$_POST[FirstName]', '$_POST[LastName]', '$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Phone]','$_POST[Year]','$_POST[Major]')";

$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result)
{
    print("Error - The query could not be executed");
    $error = mysql_error();
    print("<p>:" . $error . "</p>");
    exit;
}

echo("1 record added");

?>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific when you say it "will not call the PHP script"?

Comment: Yes, when I click the submit button, the page remains the same with the filled in data. It's a class project, so I have it up right now:

Comment: http://zweb.cs.utexas.edu/users/cs329e/nemo008/Final_Project/join_MDC.html

Comment: Uh, yea. Not sure if it's appropriate to get professionals to help with your finals project. I think the professor might have a problem with that. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The button type for the submit is wrongly defined.
It should be :-

```
<input type="submit" ...// instead of type="button"
```

You can take a look how the input tag works :- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/input

Comment: Thanks ajreal, the form submits now!

Answer (score 2):

you have did mistake in your

```
<input type="button" ../>
```

write instead

```
<input type="submit" ../>
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (!er)` there is a `$` missing.
Try to execute your query directly in your DBMS, as I receive the following error

> Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Make sure your database is correct, at first.